# VB 6.0 - Formatting Date

Tags: vb6

I've created a program and I'm trying to make it a lot more efficient. There are textboxes in it requiring entries from the user. When all the required information is in, a report is being generated in another multiline textbox. It is really important that the Date shown in the generated report is of this format "dd/MM/yy". I've already used this code below :

```
Dim a as String
a = Format(Textbox1.text, "dd/MM/yy")
```

However the only thing this does is that when someone types the date with this format "dd-MM-yy" it converts it to the one one I want. But when someone uses "." (dd.MM.yy) or even " "(dd MM yy) it doesn't convert it. Is there a way for me to extract the characters from the entried date no matter how it is being written and convert it to the one I want ?

Comment: Enforce a format with a Masked Edit Box or DatePicker

Comment: Is there anyway to add a Mask at a textbox or should I remake it again ?

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the toolbox, select `Components...` and scroll down to `Microsoft Windows Common Controls-2 6.0 (SP6)` (or something similar).  This will add more controls to the toolbox.  The control you want to use is the `DTPicker` control.

To get the date in your required format, use

```
Dim a As String
a = Format(DTPicker1.Value, "dd/MM/yy")
```