# VB 6.0 - Formating Textbox "dd/MM/yy"

Tags: vb6

I've made a question previously about this but I didn't express really what I wanted. I have a textbox that requires the user to write a Date in it. Then he can press a button and generate a report based on the entries on some other textboxes. It is really important that the date in the generated report is in this format "dd/MM/yy".

I use this code :

```
Dim a as String
a = Format(Textbox1.text, "dd/MM/yy")
```

Everything is working fine except when the user types a date in this format "dd.MM.yy" e.g 15.05.15 . When this happens, the date in the generated report is always "30/12/99". Can some1 help me understand why this is happening ?

EDIT: Regarding the Duplicate Question. In the previous question I asked how I can extract characters from a textbox and form a date in the format I want. This question is about a specific problem that happens when a specific type of format is used in the textbox (dd.MM.yy) that prints a specific date always (30/12/99).

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB 6.0 - Formating Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30347695/vb-6-0-formating-date)  Please do not post the same question just hours later.

Comment: Regarding the Duplicate Question. In the previous question I asked how I can extract characters from a textbox and form a date in the format I want. This question is about a specific problem that happens when a specific type of format is used in the textbox (dd.MM.yy) that prints a specific date always (30/12/99).

Comment: It might seem like 2 different questions but they have the same answer - don't allow the user to enter an invalid date format, see my answer on your other question.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't answer my question here though. I'm asking why does the 30/12/99 appear instead of the typed date.

Comment: Use a datetimepicker to enter dates not a textbox, then you don't have to worry about formatting at all

Comment: @MattWilko: I was just typing the exact same thing. Top and bottom of it is that you can _never_ rely on the user to enter the date in the format you are expecting.

Comment: It shows up like 30/12/99 because that's is possibly your null date format for your code.

If you are having problems on converting "15.05.15" to a date, replace the period with / and do add an additional code on your program to check if it is a real date (try and catch included :) ).

Comment: Use a control other than a textbox. Choose the DateTime picker, or the MaskEditBox where you can better control what the user enters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can chose which keys you allow in the textbox.

for example as follows:

```
'1 form with:
'  1 textbox : name=Text1

Option Explicit

Private Sub Text1_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
'  Caption = CStr(KeyAscii)
  KeyAscii = DateOnly(KeyAscii)
End Sub

Private Function DateOnly(intKey As Integer) As Integer
  Dim intResult As Integer
  intResult = intKey
  Select Case intKey
    Case vbKeyBack        'allow backspace
    Case vbKey0 To vbKey9 'allow numbers
    Case 45               'allow -
'    Case 46               'change . into /
'      intResult = 47
    Case 47               'allow /
    Case Else             'dont allow anything else
      intResult = 0
  End Select
  DateOnly = intResult
End Function
```

this just limits which keys the user can enter, you will still have to pay attention to other invalid inputs

**[EDIT]**

I added `Case 45` to the code above.

In the select case you specify what happens to each key input:

- you allow the key unaltered by specifying nothing, as i did with the / (ascii value 47)
- you can change the key to another key, as i did with the . (ascii value 46)
- you can reject the key input by setting it to 0, as i did with all other keys (case else)

You can find out which ascii value a specific key has by uncommenting the first line in Text1_KeyPress so the ascii value will show in the form caption

Comment: Hey Thanks for your answer. It seems to be a really good way to do what I want. Can you tell me how to also allow the "-" character ?

Comment: i edited my code example to add the "-" character, and added a small explanation in my post

Comment: I've searched for the Ascii Table and I found out how I do that. In order to remove any chances that the user will use another symbol other than "/" i've changed your code to change every symbol to "/" and now It works amazingly well. Thanks for your input Hrqls.

Comment: well done! ... be careful though as the user could input an incorrect date as "31/31/31" or "0/0/0" or "///" or "12/5" or anything else

Answer (score 4):

30/12/1899 is the Date equivalent of 0, this is what you get when you try to convert a `String` which is not in a correct date format to a `Date`.

To verify this, type any old rubbish into your text box and you will get 30/12/99 as output.

Regarding using a `DateTimePicker` control, see my answer to your other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30350932/61989)

Answer (score 1):

The **IsDate** Function is also useful.  This will check if the date entered is valid, and return True if it is.

```
IsDate ("21/05/2015")   'returns 'True'
IsDate ("21.05.2015")   'returns 'False'
```

You could use the **Replace** function to change "." to "/"

```
mydate = Replace("21.05.2015", ".", "/")   ' gives "21/05/2015"
```